Load json files in Bicep - with dynamic names
Is it possible to load json file in the bicep from a dynamic name ?
e.g.
var environment = 'dev'
var mydata = loadJsonContent('../configs/rules_${environment}.json')

I would need to read files with different configurations depending on the environment.
Thank you in advance for all your suggestions and help

how are you running your bicep file, az cli? you can always use a json file as parameter.

and you can also use bicepparam file, is it not an option for you?


Reading files with different configurations depending on the environment using bicep.

In bicep as per GitHub while using loadJsonContent the file should be known and fixed we cannot vary this input while execution itself. Which was not supports dynamic inputs in the parameters.
Instead, you can try the following approach by the changing the value of parameter from the deployment command.
rules_dev.json:
{
  "ruleName": "DevRule",
  "rulePriority": "High"
}

same way does for rules.prod.json & now
Now let's as your requirement is for dev
main.bicep:
param environment string = 'dev'

var configData = environment == 'dev' ? loadJsonContent('./rules_dev.json') : loadJsonContent('./rules_prod.json')

resource ruleSet 'Microsoft.Resources/deploymentScripts@2020-10-01' = {
  name: 'vinayRuleSet'
  location: resourceGroup().location
  kind: 'AzureCLI'
  properties: {
    azCliVersion: '2.0.80'
    scriptContent: 'echo "Applying rules..."'
    arguments: '--rule-name ${configData.ruleName} --rule-priority ${configData.rulePriority}'
    retentionInterval: 'P1D'
    timeout: 'PT30M'
  }
}

output ruleName string = configData.ruleName
output rulePriority string = configData.rulePriority

Use the command mentioned as below for deployment.
az deployment group create --resource-group vinay-rg --template-file main.bicep --parameters environment=dev

where you are mentioning the particular environment from the parameter input as per the requirement
Deployment:

for further understanding
refer:
https://github.com/Azure/bicep/issues/413
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/bicep/parameter-files?tabs=Bicep#parameter-type-formats

But how to deal with such an approach with more than two env types? dev, prod, stage, test, ....

you need declare them as show here .. var configFilePath = environment == 'dev' ? '../configs/rules_dev.json' :
environment == 'prod' ? '../configs/rules_prod.json' :
environment == 'stage' ? '../configs/rules_stage.json' :
environment == 'test' ? '../configs/rules_test.json' : '../configs/default_rules.json' this will ensure the input command from environment string

oh yes. Thank you
